# Using RestTemplate getForObject method

Tags: java, android, json, resttemplate

I have to call a REST web-service and I am planning to use Rest Template.

I looked at examples on how to make a GET request but I don't really understand how to use

the `getForObject`method

In my case

request is a `string`

response=is an `arraylist<URI>`

I have create a class named `ObjectExchanged`

```
   public class ObjectExchanged {
@JsonProperty
String request;
ArrayList<URI> response;
  }
```

Then

```
    getRestTemplate()).getForObject(URL, ObjectExchanged.class, ??);
```

What Should I put in the third field

Answer (score 0):

Why you want 3rd field??

```
getForObject(uri,ObjectExchanged.class); will work

getForObject(java.lang.String s, java.lang.Class<T> tClass, java.lang.Object... objects) throws org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException; 
getForObject(java.lang.String s, java.lang.Class<T> tClass, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> stringMap) throws org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException; 
getForObject(java.net.URI uri, java.lang.Class<T> tClass) throws org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
```

these are the 3 type of implementation

Comment: I thins it depend from the URL format as 

they said the third field is to expand the template